# How to fill a Combo Box from a text file - GTK - C

Tags: c, combobox, gtk, glade

I'm having trouble filling my combo box from a text file I have. Let's say I have a text file of 10 lines (each line containing a word). Using my code, the combo box will end up having 10 items of the last line.

My actual text file is of this format:

```
2p1 23 blocA 
2p2 16 blocB 
2p3 19 blocB
```

Here is the initial code I used:

```
    GtkWidget *create_class_combo ()
    {
       GList *glist = NULL;
       GtkWidget *combo;

       FILE *fp = NULL;
       Class c;

       combo = gtk_combo_new ();

       fp = fopen ("lists/class.txt","r");

       while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s \n", c.name, c.children, c.location) != EOF)
       {
           glist = g_list_append (glist, c.name);
       }

       fclose(fp);

       gtk_combo_set_popdown_strings (GTK_COMBO (combo), glist);

       return combo;
    }
```

This is the Class structure:

```
    typedef struct Class
    {
       char name[20];
       char children[10];
       char location[30];
    } Class;
```

After some testing, it turns out that "g_list_append" will overwrite the last item it added with the new one, if you use the same variable as second parameter.

So, I used an array of strings. It didn't work. It shows me an empty combo box.

I used an array of a structure that contains only one string. It didn't work. It shows me an empty combo box.

I used g_list_concat alongside a second GList variable, while also initializing the first one at the end of each "while" cycle. It didn't work as well.

I'm just puzzled. 
Can you please help me?

Update: I found different functions for combo box and used them instead in this code. It works now.

```
GtkWidget *create_class_combo ()
{
GtkWidget *combo;

FILE *fp = NULL;
Class c;

combo = gtk_combo_box_text_new_with_entry ();

fp = fopen ("lists/class.txt","r");

while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s \n", c.name, c.children, c.location) == 3)
{
    gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT (combo), c.name);
}

fclose(fp);

return combo;
}
```

Comment: Your `fscanf()` is wrong. You should check against `3` and not `EOF`. The way it is now it is probably causing undefined behavior. You should also check that the values are being read and not only appended to the list.

Comment: @iharob "fscanf()" is working correctly. I tested it and that's how I always use it. I keep scanning until I hit EOF to make sure I traversed all my file. The values are also read and stored into the variables correctly.

You can try making a "name" string. Give it a value. Append it to the glist. Then give it another value. Append it again to the same list. The list will appear as two items having the same value as the last one you appended.

Comment: You always use it WRONG. Read the documentation. Your code is prone to Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that correction, but it's not the issue here. Try what I said and it will reproduce the same result I'm having.

Something like this:


              char name[10];

              strcpy(name, "mike");

              glist = g_list_append (glist, name);

              strcpy(name, "john");

              glist = g_list_append (glist, name);

You will have a list like this:
john
jhon

Comment: Please read my answer. The second point, you can use a `GtkTreeModel` and that will allow way more than just text and a single column in the combo box. It's also easier.

Comment: Note that AFAIK `append_text` is deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, your `fscanf()` call returns the number of matches and you are not checking that, it could be returning `0` and not `EOF` because there was no match and also the end of file wasn't reached in the previous read operation, so you need to check that it returns `3` not `EOF`.

   Also, you should try to prevent a buffer overflow. You can use a length modifier for the `"%s"` specifier and use the length of the target array - 1.

   Finally, the middle value in every line seems to be an integer so you may use `"%4s%d%6s"` as the format parameter to `fscanf()` and remember, check against `3` not `EOF`.
2. You should read on how to fill a combo box in [gtk+](https://www.gtk.org). You can use a `GtkTreeModel` and `GtkTreeIter`s to fill it very easily and the way you would do it would be very clear too.

   Another benefit is that you would have much more control on what data your combo box items hold, you can use multiple columns, store extra data that you would easily retrieve from the model.

This is an example of how to do it, error handling should be improved a lot

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef enum Columns {
    Name, Children, Location, ColumnsCount
} Columns;

static GtkWidget *
create_and_populate_combo_box()
{
    GtkListStore *model;
    GtkWidget *combo;
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GtkCellRenderer *column;
    char name[4];
    int children;
    char location[6];
    FILE *file;
    // Create a new list store
    model = gtk_list_store_new(ColumnsCount,
                                      G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_INT, G_TYPE_STRING);
    if (model == NULL)
        return NULL;
    // Create the combo box
    combo = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(model));
    if (combo == NULL)
        return NULL;
    // Create a cell renderer to render text only (this is a basic one)
    column = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    if (column == NULL)
        return NULL;
    // Install the cell renderer and set the text column
    gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo), column, TRUE);
    gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo),
                                                    column, "text", Name, NULL);
    // Read data from the file
    file = fopen("data.dat", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL;
    while (fscanf(file, "%4s%d%6s", name, &children, location) == 3) {
        gtk_list_store_append(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter,
                        Name, name, Children, children, Location, location, -1);
    }
    fclose(file);
    // Set the first value as active
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), 0);
    return combo;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *combo;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    if (window == NULL)
        return -1;
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
                                               G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    combo = create_and_populate_combo_box();
    if (combo == NULL)
        return -1;
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 100, -1);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), combo);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying about fscanf(). I'll begin using it this way instead. Thanks.

I'll take a look at using a GtkTreeModel and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks alot for your detailed answer. This solution gives lots of options to customize my combo box. I also found another solution after looking around a bit. I updated my first post with it.